# Keeping java socket alive while multi request comes in

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Here is my server app

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ISOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Server siap menerima koneksi pada port ["+PORT+"]");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                InputStreamReader inStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                PrintWriter sendMsg = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

                int data;
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                int counter = 0;

                int lengthOfMsg = 4;
                while((data = inStreamReader.read()) != 0) {
                    counter++;
                    sb.append((char) data);
                    if (counter == 4) lengthOfMsg += Integer.valueOf(sb.toString());

                    if (lengthOfMsg == sb.toString().length()) {
                        System.out.println("Rec. Msg ["+sb.toString()+"] len ["+sb.toString().length()+"]");
                        processingMsg(sb.toString(), sendMsg); 
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
            }

        }
    }
```

the problem is if the client doesn't close the connection, the server app can't receive another request form another client

and if I do closing the connection from server side, it won't work with the client's apps.

The point is in this server or client app closing the connection can't be done

**What I want is: is there any way so the server can keep receive some request from client, even though another request not yet finished. so my server app can receive multi request at the same time without closing any connection.**

Please help me,

nb: client's apps is from my third party vendor, so I have to follow their rules

Comment: You need more threads. You have a single thread which will be used for a single client, when after `accept()` you should be creating a new thread to handle that connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a runnable thread. 
This keeps your server alive up until you close it and whether the client disconnects.
Try this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ISOException {
        final ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){

            try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Server siap menerima koneksi pada port ["+PORT+"]");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();

            InputStreamReader inStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter sendMsg = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

            int data;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            int counter = 0;

            int lengthOfMsg = 4;
            while((data = inStreamReader.read()) != 0) {
                counter++;
                sb.append((char) data);
                if (counter == 4) lengthOfMsg += Integer.valueOf(sb.toString());

                if (lengthOfMsg == sb.toString().length()) {
                    System.out.println("Rec. Msg ["+sb.toString()+"] len ["+sb.toString().length()+"]");
                    processingMsg(sb.toString(), sendMsg); 
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
        }

    }


        }
    }).start();


}
```

If this doesn't work for you, you can refer to my code.

```
String ip = "";

        try(final DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket()){
            socket.connect(InetAddress.getByName("8.8.8.8"), 10002);
            ip = socket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
        txt.append("SERVER STARTED\n");
        txt.append("Server IP Address: " + ip + "\n\n");

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            while (true) {
                Server.this.txt.append("Waiting for file...\n");
                final ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8998);
                server.close();
                server = new ServerSocket(8998);
                Server.this.socket = server.accept();

                final Date date = new Date();
                final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
                final String curDate = dateFormat.format(date);


                final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Server.this.socket.getInputStream()));
                final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(Server."C:\\Test\\File-" + curDate + ".csv"));
                try {

                    String line;

                    for (line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {

                        wordsarray = line.split("\t");
                        pw.println(line);


                    }
                    pw.flush();
                    pw.close();


                }
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.printf("Can't write to file. ", ex);
                }
                finally {
                    if (Server.this.socket != null) {
                        br.close();
                        pw.close();
                        server.close();
                        Server.this.txt.append("\nAutomatically Saved to " + "C:\\PDT\\DataScan\\PurchaseOrder-" + curDate + ".csv" + "\n\n");

                       System.out.printf("Success! ");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.printf("Something's Wrong! \n" + e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Server.this, e + "\n\nThe server needs to restart.", "Something's Wrong!", 1);
            dispose();
            main(null);

        }
    }
}).start();
```

It stays alive up until I close the server or the application and also handles multiple connections/requests.

Comment: at part `serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);` show up an error
"local variable referenced from inner class must be final or effectively final"

Comment: I guess you should just declare it as final, refer to my edited code, or you can also declare the server at the thread class like what I did  `final ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8998);`

Comment: Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that `try` block. Instead you are catching all your exceptions immediately and then proceeding as though they didn't happen. Don't write code like this.